# How to validate an empty search string

Tags: php, search

I'm trying to do a search with multiple keywords. For testing purposes ,the search string looks like this

```
http://localhost/admin/search.php?search=live+concert
```

So far, the search works perfectly!!!

If there is no parameters, im able to echo a message

```
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {

   // split keywords
   $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $_GET['search']);

   // search

} else {
   echo 'Nothing to search';
}
```

Here's my problem. When I hit the search button without entering keywords, i get an empty string , like this

```
http://localhost/admin/search.php?search=
```

I want to echo an error to the user saying that there is no keywords to search for. I've tried using **count($keywords)**, but i always get 1 as a result when no keywords have been entered.

How do i check if the user hit the search button without entering keyword(s) ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try php's `empty` method? It is different from `isset`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `trim($_GET['search'])` where you remove any additional spaces and check if then `$_GET['search']` is not `''` this way even if the user only submits space, your error message shows

```
if (isset($_GET['search']) && trim($_GET['search']) != '') {
```

Comment: "isset" is entirely unnecessary. The variable will be set as it has been posted by the form. A simple (!$_GET['search']) or even (!trim($_GET['search'])) will suffice.

Comment: @JBES if you don't use isset first, you may get a warning that trim is using an unset variable, so it is better to use isset first, then run the trim, so if I visit the the page through a direct link, the without a query string the $_GET won't be set

Comment: You have completely missed the point. The variable WILL be set as it is being posted by the form. My answer stands. Additionally, !='' is also unnecessary as all that is required is a leading ! (logical NOT operator - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: @JBES if I visit the page like this: http://localhost/admin/search.php directly in the browser is $_GET['search'] set?

Comment: JBES: with your method i get the error: Notice: Undefined index: search. so it's better to validate the $_GET. Also, i like not to use empty since who knows if someone searches for 0.
_

Comment: @Marco - Then unfortunately you are displaying "Nothing to search" whether a search has been initiated or not? That is simply bad practice. As you like...

Comment: JBES: I believe it's better to display 'Nothing to search' then getting the system error 'Notice: Undefined index: search'. My message  can always be changed to something more appropriate, since my app is still BETA. Bad practice? I don't think so... Your method and the error i get is very poor practice.

Comment: still, your answer gives me an error. Who's going to use a method that gives an error? seriously... CodeBird method is more robust and better practice. How childish of you to give a -1 on my answer. Just accepted, you can't always be right...

Comment: @JBES just for the info, how can he test a form with method get in your opinion, how could he test if the form was submitted or not? Question 2 if he is using get that he might want people to share urls that give results without having to submit a form, what's your solution for that?

Comment: Bad practice = Does Google tell you it has found no results if you haven't searched for anything? It looks amateur. Very simple: Use a control variable. For POST submissions simply use the "submit" variable or define one for GET submissions. Not rocket science.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able try something like this:

```
if (empty($_GET['search'])) {
    echo 'You did not enter anything';
}
```

`empty` checks to see if the var is either 0, empty, or not set at all. Not that this matters but as of PHP 5.5 empty() supports expressions, rather than only variables.

Comment: "empty" is entirely unnecessary. The variable will be set as it has been posted by the form. A simple (!$_GET['search']) will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple validation as below, this will check if "search" is posted and its not NULL or not having a while space and length is greater than 0

```
if (isset($_GET['search']) && strlen(trim($_GET['search']))>0) {
 // do the search
}else{
 echo 'Nothing to search';
}
```

Comment: `strlen(trim($_GET['search'])) > 0` would be a lot less clunky as `trim($_GET['search']) !== ''`.  (`''` is the only string value that will ever have a length of 0.)

Answer (score 2):

If the user has clicked the search button, $_GET['search'] will be set but empty, which is why your 'isset' condition is failing. Why not a simple:

```
if (!trim($_GET['search'])){ //trim removes whitespace from beginning and end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if ($_GET['search'] == '') {/*ERROR*/}` or `if (strlen($_GET['search']) < 1) {/*ERROR*/}`.

*These could also be added to your already existing if statement.*

The problem with using count is that when you place an empty string as the second argument for `preg_split()`, an array with one empty string value will be returned: `array('')`.  Therefore, the amount of values in the array will be one.

Comment: $keywords after preg_split will be an array hence unfortunately neither of your solutions would work...

Answer (score 1):

The [empty](https://www.php.net/empty) function should work -

```
if ( isset($_GET['search']) && !empty(trim($_GET['search'])) )
```